# Java setPressedIcon not working

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I have menu in my application, and I want to set menu item normal state icon, and pressed state icon. Normal state icon is added, but when I press menu item, normal state icon is not changed by pressed state icon. What is problem here:

```
        JMenu m=new JMenu(text);
        m.setBackground(getTheme().colors.menuColor());
        m.setOpaque(false);
        m.setIcon(core.getIcon(text, "normal"));
        m.setPressedIcon(core.getIcon("webmaps", "pressed"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been [seen before](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2145169). The inherited [setPressedIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setPressedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) does not change the background `Icon` on the the `JMenu` (or indeed `JMenuItem`). You could use a `MenuListener` on the component as a workaround:

```
m.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        JMenu menu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
        menu.setIcon(core.getIcon("webmaps", "pressed"));
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        JMenu menu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
        menu.setIcon(core.getIcon(text, "normal"));
    }

    @Override
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
        JMenu menu = (JMenu) e.getSource();
        menu.setIcon(core.getIcon(text, "normal"));
    }
});
```