# Java - setSelectedIcon() and setPressedIcon() do not seem to register

Tags: java, swing, icons, contextmenu, jpopupmenu

I have a [JPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html) on a JTree with JCheckboxMenuItem's where I would like to use custom icons (Windows L&F). I'm able to use setIcon() on a JCheckboxMenuItem successfully, but for some reason setSelectedIcon() and setPressedIcon() do not appear to work.

The code below is complete and will compile without error. However, it simply does not work. I've confirmed that the images are loaded correctly by setting them via setIcon() and seeing them there.

In doing some research I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034573/java-setpressedicon-not-working), so I tried to implement a workaround using that but it doesn't seem to work using JPopupMenu. I'm trying to figure out a possible workaround with JPopupMenu but I'm having trouble. I was thinking about adding a mouselistener but I want it to respond to keyboard events as well... Menulistener's unfortunately do not work on JPopupMenu's.

Here is the compilable, error-free code:

```
package mypackage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class test extends JFrame {

    public static final ImageIcon icon_properties   = new ImageIcon(mypackage.class.getResource("options.png"));
    public static final ImageIcon icon_checked      = new ImageIcon(mypackage.class.getResource("checkbox_checked.png"));
    public static final ImageIcon icon_unchecked    = new ImageIcon(mypackage.class.getResource("checkbox_unchecked.png"));
    public static final ImageIcon icon_pressed      = new ImageIcon(mypackage.class.getResource("checkbox_pressed.png"));

    String SINGLE_LEFT      = "single left click";
    String SINGLE_MIDDLE    = "single middle click";
    String SINGLE_RIGHT     = "single right click";
    String DOUBLE_LEFT      = "double left click";
    String DOUBLE_MIDDLE    = "double middle click";
    String DOUBLE_RIGHT     = "double right click";

    String MENU_VISIBLE     = "Visible";
    String MENU_SELECTABLE  = "Selectable";
    String MENU_DRAGGABLE   = "Draggable";
    String MENU_PROPERTIES  = "Properties";

    protected JTree  theTree;
    protected DefaultMutableTreeNode theModel;

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

    public test() {
        setSize(400, 300);
        theModel = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LayerList") {
            {
                String NODE_NAME = " this is an item to select ";
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
                node_icon = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(NODE_NAME));
                add(node_icon);
            }
        };

        theTree = new JTree(theModel);
        theTree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Angled");
        theTree.setRootVisible(false);
        theTree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        theTree.setEditable(false);

        MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int selRow = theTree.getRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                TreePath selPath = theTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if(selRow != -1) {
                    if( SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) ) {
                        if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(SINGLE_LEFT, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                        else if(e.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(DOUBLE_LEFT, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                    }
                    else if( SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(e) ) {
                        if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(SINGLE_MIDDLE, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                        else if(e.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(DOUBLE_MIDDLE, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                    }
                    else if( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) ) {
                        if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(SINGLE_RIGHT, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                        else if(e.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                            ContextMenuClickHander(DOUBLE_RIGHT, selRow, selPath, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        theTree.addMouseListener(ml);
        JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane();
        s.getViewport().add(theTree);
        getContentPane().add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); } });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ContextMenu extends JPopupMenu implements ActionListener {
        JCheckBoxMenuItem item;
        public ContextMenu(){
            item = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(MENU_VISIBLE);
            item.setIcon(icon_unchecked);
            item.setSelectedIcon(icon_checked);
            item.setPressedIcon(icon_pressed);
            //item.setRolloverIcon(icon_checked);
            //item.setRolloverSelectedIcon(icon_checked);
            //item.setDisabledIcon(icon_checked);
            //item.setDisabledSelectedIcon(icon_checked);
            item.setActionCommand(MENU_VISIBLE);
            item.addActionListener(this);
            add(item);

            item = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(MENU_SELECTABLE);
            item.setIcon(icon_unchecked);
            item.setSelectedIcon(icon_checked);
            item.setPressedIcon(icon_pressed);
            item.setActionCommand(MENU_SELECTABLE);
            item.addActionListener(this);
            add(item);

            item = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(MENU_DRAGGABLE);
            item.setIcon(icon_unchecked);
            item.setSelectedIcon(icon_checked);
            item.setPressedIcon(icon_pressed);
            item.setActionCommand(MENU_DRAGGABLE);
            item.addActionListener(this);
            add(item);

            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(MENU_PROPERTIES+"...");
            item.setIcon(icon_properties);
            item.setActionCommand(MENU_PROPERTIES);
            item.addActionListener(this);
            add(item);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (MENU_VISIBLE.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                System.out.println("Clicked "+MENU_VISIBLE);
                ChangeIcon(e);
            }
            else if (MENU_SELECTABLE.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                System.out.println("Clicked "+MENU_SELECTABLE);
                ChangeIcon(e);
            }
            else if (MENU_DRAGGABLE.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                System.out.println("Clicked "+MENU_DRAGGABLE);
                ChangeIcon(e);
            }
            else if (MENU_PROPERTIES.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                System.out.println("Clicked "+MENU_PROPERTIES);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeIcon(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof AbstractButton) {
            boolean selected = ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).isSelected();
            if( selected ) {
                ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(icon_checked);
            }
            else {
                ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(icon_unchecked);
            }
        }
    }

    void ContextMenuClickHander(String clickType, int row, TreePath tpath, MouseEvent e) {
        theTree.setSelectionPath(tpath);
        System.out.println(clickType+": row="+row+", treepath="+tpath);
        if( clickType.equals(SINGLE_RIGHT) ) {
            menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception evt) {}
        new test().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Here are the images I'm trying to use, if that helps:
 - checked: [image: checked] https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqbKI.png
 - unchecked: [image: unchecked] https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN0Zd.png
 - pressed: [image: pressed] https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS4pb.png

#### Update:

A not-entirely perfect workaround I've developed so far is to manually set the icon each time a click is detected. In the "actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)" function after each println statement add a new line with "ChangeIcon(e);", and when that's done just add in this function:

However, the Windows L&F seems to still add it's own hover/selected border (See image). I'm hoping someone still has a real solution...
[image: not so perfect workaround]

#### Update 2:

Updated complete code with first update code, tightened up post a bit.

Comment: Hope that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034573/java-setpressedicon-not-working/15035417#15035417) will help you

Comment: In my 3rd paragraph ("*In doing some research...*") I point out that I've looked at that question. Unfortunately, you cannot add a menuListener to a JPopupMenu, but the workaround that I use (shown in the code above) functionally does the same thing (as long as the user is clicking the menu). No fix yet though for the blue border that shows when a menu item is selected.